# Entity Framework - simple operation gives Format exception - Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1

Entity Framework is giving a pretty cryptic error message when I try to do a simple Add operation.

```
_context.Users.Add(new User
{
     DateJoined = DateTime.UtcNow
});
_context.SaveChanges();

FormatException:  Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
```

User inherits from `IdentityUser` from `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`

I crossed check the database and model and I cant seem to identify what property is causing the problem. The models contains:

1. ints, bools, and strings - get default values
2. one non-nullable DateTime property (DateJoined) that I provide
3. one nullable DateTime property
4. one enum that correctly defaults to 0
5. virtual ICollections

I don't undestand what property is causing the issue, how can I know more specifically? Could it be something else? The exception dialog doesnt contain the familiar link to view the inner exception.

Comment: How did you initialize `Users` in your DbContext class?

Comment: Well my `ApplicationDbContext` inherits `IdentityDbContext<User>` so Users is provided on the base class `public virtual IDbSet<TUser> Users { get; set; }`. I don't initialize it.

Comment: Are you sure your suggestion is in the context of Entity Framework because I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: How is the user primary key defined in the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To know more about what is going on, try to do the following:

1) Add an [Interceptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx) to see the underlying database operation. From the logs, you can see the INSERT command and probably see what is going on by comparing it to the table constraints.

2) Put a breakpoint on the SaveChanges and see the tracked entities from the `Context` object. Make sure that this user is the only added entity and marked as dirty. From there you can also see its properties

3) In you model, mark all non-mandatory properties as `[NonMapped]` one by one. Spot the problematic property this way. If those properties where inherited from the base class, you can mark them as `NonMapped` programmatically in your database configuration class.

4) If non of the above works, try using [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to do your insert (from `1)` )and see if you get a better error message

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the user a username, e.g.

```
_context.Users.Add(new User
{
    UserName = "Bob",
    DateJoined = DateTime.UtcNow
});
_context.SaveChanges();
```